# Auto-scaled image not shown correctly with IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

first of all: this is not my code, that's why I don't understand most parts of it.

I have a webpage that is showing an image right beside a UL-list. The size of this image is scaled automatically according to the available visible width in browser. This CSS/HTML code works fine for Chrome, Opera, Firefox but it fails miserably with IE 10. There only a horizontal line is shown, means the image is scaled to one pixel height.

That's how the image is embedded into webpage:

```
<div id="eth_group">
 <div id="eth_list">
  <ul>
   <li>here is my list
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="eth_image">
  <img src="img/myimg.png" border=0 align="right" width="100%" height="auto"; />
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the related CSS file:

```
#eth_group{display:table;}
#eth_list{display:table-cell;float:left;width:65%}
#eth_image{float:left;width:35%;display:table-cell;}
/* --------- MEDIA !   800  --------------  */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
#eth_group{display:inline;}
#eth_list{display:block;width:100%;}
#eth_image{width:80%;display:block;marigin:0 auto;}
}
```

Anybody an idea what has t obe changed to let the image show correctly in IE too?

Thanks :-)

Comment: You have a mistake in your #eth_image CSS - "marigin" instead of "margin".

Comment: danmullen: thanks but this was not the reason. also adding a "height:auto; does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was caused by the

```
 height="auto";
```

in IMG-tag.